# Show (diagnostic) messages in render pane while rendering Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

With one of the recent updates of `knitr` the output in the render pane in RStudio became less cluttered in so far that only the information about the current chunk is shown, instead of adding all rendering information to the log.

However, since this change I am struggling to add my timing hooks properly.

Let's take this sample document:

````
---
title: "TimeMe"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
message(paste("Compiling started at:", Sys.time()))
start_compiling <- Sys.time()
chunk_timings <- data.frame(chunk = character(0), timing = numeric(0))
options(warn = 1)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE)

knitr::knit_hooks$set(time_it = local({
   now <- NULL
   function(before, options) {
      if (before) {
         # record the current time before each chunk
         now <<- Sys.time()
      } else {
         # calculate the time difference after a chunk
         res <- difftime(Sys.time(), now, units = "secs")
         # return a character string to show the time
         chunk_timings <<- rbind(
            chunk_timings,
            data.frame(chunk = options$label, timing = res)
         )
         message(glue::glue("# {options$label}: {round(res, 2)}s"))
      }
   }
}))
```

```{r libs}
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
```


```{r wait-1}
Sys.sleep(1)
```

```{r wait-2}
Sys.sleep(2)
```

```{r wait-5}
Sys.sleep(5)
```


```{r finis-artis}
local({
   n_slow <- 5L
   res <- difftime(Sys.time(), start_compiling, units = "secs")
   message(glue("Total Compiling Time: {round(res, 2)}s"))
   slowest <- capture.output(chunk_timings %>% 
                                as_tibble() %>% 
                                arrange(desc(timing)) %>% 
                                slice(1:n_slow)) %>% 
      paste(collapse = "\n")
   message(glue("TOP {n_slow} Slowest Chunks:\n{slowest}"))
   message(glue("Compiling finished at: {Sys.time()}"))
})
```
````

If you render it you see the following `Render` output in the render pane in Rstudio:

[image: Render Output Gif of Rtstudio with no timing]

You will observe that the `message` form the last chunk (`finis-artis`) is **not** shown in the render pane.

This is strange because if you turn on the `timing` by changing the default options of the chunks

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      time_it = TRUE)
```

You see at least that the messages from the previous chunks are added to the render pane (though distorting the new cleaned log somehow):

[image: Render Output Gif of Rtstudio with timing]

Regardless of what I try, I cannot display the `message` from the last chunk in the render pane.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to send any message to the render pane (at any time, but with the new look and feel of the render output it makes sense to do that only at the end)

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant: https://yihui.org/en/2022/12/message-false/

Comment: Yes you nailed it, setting `message = NA` did indeed the trick (after updating `evaluate`). Definitely need to read about the new opportunities offered by `knitr.progress.fun`. If you want to bother about a short answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **knitr** >= v1.42 and **evaluate** >= v0.20, you need to set the chunk option `message = NA` to send messages to `stderr`. This is equivalent to `message = FALSE` in previous versions of **knitr** and **evaluate**.